# Do independent events always come in clusters?

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading a website that reports occurrences in commercial aviation. Recently there have been a number of similar incidents involving tyre problems (tyre damage, blown tyres, etc) on different airlines.

Several readers noted how this tyre events have apparently clustered based on the increase of the frequency of the events in a very concentrated period of time (a peak in frequency).

One reader made the following comment, which caught my attention:

> If the tyre events happen randomly, completely independently from each
>   other, then they will fall in clusters. If they didn't, i.e. if they
>   fell at equal intervals apart, that would imply some guiding force
>   making it happen that way. So yes you can see clusters, and that's a
>   good thing.

**Is this statement correct?**

I feel that it might be correct in part, since I relate the part of the sentence *"if they fell at equal intervals apart, that would imply some guiding force"* to the uniform distribution, which seems unnatural or artificial.

Comment: The anecdotal evidence for this is mainly because we are more likely to notice clusters.

Comment: I think that what's true is that it is *unlikely* not to have *any clusters*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.

In a Poisson process (a reasonable model for this system), under the condition that a given number of events have occurred in an interval, the distribution of these events over that period will be uniform.   Thus the expected order statistics will be evenly spaced over that interval.

However, in actual sample data, it should be anticipated that their will be some *variance* from that expectation, and that will appear as clustering.   Discovering *less* variance in the periodicity means that something is not entirely *random* about the process.

Of course, the contrary also holds.   If the variance is significantly *greater* than calculated, that *too* would indicate another influence.